# JPA + SPRING=DAO. Dynamic Parameter List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dao

I can't resolve error with dynamic parameter list "where in". Another query working

@NamedQuery(name = "News.delete", query = "DELETE n FROM News n WHERE n.newsId in (:ids)")

but

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.recover(Lantlr/RecognitionException;Lantlr/collections/impl/BitSet;)V
>           at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.optionalFromTokenFromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:400)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.deleteStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:259)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:148)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:157)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:402)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:352)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:221)
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:251)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1390)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1359)

UPD
new error

```
 public void removeNews(List<Integer> listOfIdNewsForDeleting) throws DAOException {
    EntityManager entityManager = getJpaTemplate().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();

    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("News.delete");
    query.setParameter("ids", listOfIdNewsForDeleting);
    int deleted = query.executeUpdate();}
```

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

I can't get transaction. So i can't use `JpaTemplate` pass list of id of news for deleting. Maybe `JpaCallback`

Answer (score 1):

You are having incompatible versions of hibernate and antlr. Upgrade your antlr.jar

Answer (score 0):

Use `DELETE FROM News n WHERE n.newsId in (:ids)`

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct for the reference.

Comment: @NamedQuery(name = "News.delete", query = "DELETE FROM News n WHERE n.newsId in (:ids)")

Thanks, but i get new error 

 

    public void removeNews(List<Integer> listOfIdNewsForDeleting) throws DAOException {

        EntityManager entityManager = getJpaTemplate().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();


        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("News.delete");

        query.setParameter("ids", listOfIdNewsForDeleting);

        int deleted = query.executeUpdate();

i get 

Executing an update/delete query

I can't understand what wrong. name